# Add an Object as Attribute containing Values

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

Here, in `index`, I've got a required input and a button.

```
@GetMapping("/")
public String index(Model model) {    
    // [...]
    User user = new User();
    user .setAge(25);
    model.addAttribute("user", user);
}

@PostMapping("/process_user")
public String processUser(User user) {

    // Need Age (alteady got from attribute) and Name (passed through input)
    userService.someService(user);

    return "index";
}
```

```html
<form th:action="@{/process_user}" th:object="${user}" method="post">
    <input type="text" th:field="*{name}" class="form-control" required />
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">someAction</button>
</form>
```

Notice that I used an existing object there `model.addAttribute("user", user);` with an initialized value `age` instead of giving an empty one `model.addAttribute("user", new User());`. The issue is that I'm getting a `NULL` value from `age` passed through the attribute but `name` passed through the input is OK. My question is can I pass values through attribute and get them at `/process_user`? If not, what else can I do?

Comment: Your form doesn't have an `age` field so there is nothing to pass.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks! It worked. Never thought I needed an attribute.